# adjusting the Premiere Creative Cloud sequence (newbie question)

Tags: premiere, adobe

I just downloaded Premiere CC and am learning to use it. There's a big section in the sequence (I think that's what it's called?) that I'd like to get rid of.  In the screen shot below, I marked it with the white arrow.

[image]

As you can see, my footage is a little over 2 minutes long.  However, the area I can scroll is over 12 minutes long.  How can I make the scrollable area a similar length as my footage?  I want to do that so the scroll bar isn't super-sensitive (and there's not ten useless minutes of empty space in that window). BTW, I know how to "zoom in" on that timeline. But then if you move the scroll bar a couple pixels, you've jumped several "screens" one way or the other.

Thanks!

Comment: Possibly related... http://video.stackexchange.com/questions/9933/why-is-my-premiere-timeline-scrollbar-thumb-non-proportional though it doesn't have a good answer either.

Comment: @AJHenderson Yeah, that question looks almost identical. It's for an earlier version of Premiere but I guess the functionality is the same on their latest release. (That other question didn't have an answer / solution, for what it's worth.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I can gather online, it appears that it is supposed to scale automatically and always extends 10 minutes beyond the end of the last clip in the sequence and there does not appear to be any way to change that.

Comment: Wow ... that would be terrible. I'm an interface designer, and that's not what I'd call a good interface. Seems that there should be a setting where you get to choose how many minutes (1? 5? 10?) you want it to extend.  Thanks for the research! My own searches didn't turn up that info.

Comment: You know, it isn't a great design, but it's also something I've never noticed until people mentioned it here.  Generally, when you are working with a project, either you have the whole thing in view or 10 minutes of extra space doesn't really make a big difference.  Does seem silly you can't tweak it though.

Comment: Its not the worst thing in the world. It just makes the horizontal scroll bar too sensitive.